# Storing information in value bean

Tags: jsp, servlets

Hi i have a code that queries information from database, once it gets the information the values are stored in a value bean (many rows of information can be retrieved from mysql). Should i create some thing like

```
                movie movies[i] = new movie();
                movies[i].setMovieID(rs.getInt("Movie_ID"));
                movies[i].setMovieTitle(rs.getString("Movie_Title"));
                movies[i].setReleaseDate(rs.getDate("Release_Date"));
                movies[i].setImage(rs.getString("Image"));
                movies[i].setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));

                movies.add(movies[i]);
```

-instead of-

```
 public class MovieDB {
    public ArrayList movies (String query){
        ArrayList movies= new ArrayList();

        try {
            // step 1 : load JDBC Driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //step2 : define Connection URL
            String connURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sp_movie?user=root&password=deepak1990";

            //step3 establish connection url
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

            String sql="{call "+query+"}";
            CallableStatement cs=conn.prepareCall(sql);

            ResultSet rs=cs.executeQuery();

// 1) This part

            while(rs.next()){
                movie movies1 = new movie();
                movies1.setMovieID(rs.getInt("Movie_ID"));
                movies1.setMovieTitle(rs.getString("Movie_Title"));
                movies1.setReleaseDate(rs.getDate("Release_Date"));
                movies1.setImage(rs.getString("Image"));
                movies1.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));

                movies.add(movies1);
            }
            } catch (Exception e){
            } finally {
                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
            return movies;
        }
}
```

Comment: your first option wont compile `movie movies[i] = new movie();`

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is better because there is no need to create an array of movie. You can directly get bean and add it to List. You can also set this list to request for accessing on JSP page.

```
while(rs.next())
{
                    movie movies1 = new movie();
                    movies1.setMovieID(rs.getInt("Movie_ID"));
                    movies1.setMovieTitle(rs.getString("Movie_Title"));
                    movies1.setReleaseDate(rs.getDate("Release_Date"));
                    movies1.setImage(rs.getString("Image"));
                    movies1.setDescription(rs.getString("Description"));

                    movies.add(movies1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your second form (ArrayList) is better. if you will return as array (not ArrayList) in the last line you can use `return movies.toArray(new Movie[0]);`
in the first form you have some problem.

- in the first you most know how your array most be big,(size of array).
- in the last line you use `movies.add(movies[i]);` but `movies` is a array. you can not use this method on it.  compiler cannot compile it.
- as @fmodos says your first line have problem and compiler can not compile it.